# Select specific column from multiple csv files, then merge those columns into single file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to select a specific column, with the header `"Average"`, from multiple csv files. Then take the `"Average"` column from each of those multiple csv files and merge them into a new csv file.

I left the comments in to show the other ways I tried to accomplish this:

```
procdir = r"C:\Users\ChromePnP\Desktop\exchange\processed"

collected = os.listdir(procdir)
flist = list(collected)
flist.sort()
#exclude first files in list
rest_of_files = flist[1:]
for f in rest_of_files:
    get_averages = pd.read_csv(f, usecols = ['Average'])
        #df1 = pd.DataFrame(f)
        # df2 = pd.DataFrame(rundata_file)
        #get_averages = pd.read_csv(f)
        #for col in ['Average']:
        #get_averages[col].to_csv(f_template)
    got_averages = pd.merge(get_averages, right_on = 'Average')
got_averages.to_csv("testfile.csv", index=False)
```

EDIT:

I was able to get the columns I wanted, and they will print. However now the saved file only has a single average column from the loop, instead of saving all the columns selected in the loop.

```
rest_of_files = flist[1:]
    #f.sort()
print(rest_of_files)
for f in rest_of_files:
    get_averages = pd.read_csv(f)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(get_averages)
    got_averages = df1.loc[:, ['Average']]
    print(got_averages)
f2_temp = pd.read_csv(rundata_file)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(f2_temp)
merge_averages = pd.concat([df2, got_averages], axis=1)
merge_averages.to_csv(rundata_file, index=False)
```

Comment: One error I get is **ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!"**

Comment: Can you provide some examples on how the file you used works ? I guess the error is located at the line `got_averages` ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you use `pd.merge` with argument `left` and `right` as specified [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```py
got_averages = pd.merge(got_averages, get_averages, right_on = 'Average')
```

Or you use `.merge` for dataframe, doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) :

```py
got_averages = got_averages.merge(get_averages, right_on = 'Average')
```

Keep in mind you need to initialize `got_averages` (as empty dataframe for instance) before using it in your `for` loop

Comment: I was able to use `pd.concat([df2, got_averages], axis=1)` and `got_averages = df1.loc[:, ['Average']]`, which will print the all the average columns. However, the final saved csv only has one column saved from the loop.

Comment: `get_averages = pd.read_csv(f)` and  `df1 = pd.DataFrame(get_averages)` are redundant, since `pd.read_csv` already return a dataframe (same thing about `df2` and `temp_f2`. Your main problem  is that `got_averages` is not initialized before the forloop and not append at each loop.  The fact you have only one column saved is totally expected. Let me know if you need more details, I can edit my answer

Comment: So in this case I need to initialize `rest_of_files`, and initialize means using `pd.read()`? How do I append at each loop? Editing your answer with more details would be appreciated.